# Spring session bean shared between HttpSession-s

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session-bean

I'm trying to undestand session beans in Spring.
The book I'm reading says, about them, that:

> the bean is created when needed and stored in the javax.servlet.http.HttpSession. When the session is destoyed so is the bean instance.

I tried with the following example:

The bean:

```
package com.at.test.web;

public class Cart {
    public static int dummy = 0;
    public Cart() {
        System.out.println("Cart::<init> with hashCode " + hashCode());
    }
}
```

The bean definition:

```
<beans:bean id="cartBean" class="com.at.test.web.Cart" scope="session">
    <apo:scoped-proxy/>
</beans:bean>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired 
    private Cart cart;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpSession session, Model model) {
      System.out.println("Cart is: " + cart.hashCode() 
          + " ; dummy = " + (cart.dummy++) 
          + " (" + cart.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ")" 
          + "; session is: " + session.hashCode());
      return "home.jsp";
  }
}
```

This is what happens on Tomcat startup:

```
Cart::<init> with hashCode 970109301
```

I think Spring need this instance in order to create the CGLIB proxies. Anyway, I'm not that sure.

After the startup, I use two different browsers to have two different HttpSession.
The result, when the controller is invoked, is:

```
Cart is: 578093288 ; dummy = 0 (com.at.test.web.Cart$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2eb8334f); session is: 1013723725
Cart is: 578093288 ; dummy = 1 (com.at.test.web.Cart$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2eb8334f); session is: 1060682497
```

The cart instance seems to be shared between HttpSession-s, but I was expecting two instances of Cart.

The same if I let the bean implements an interface, use annotation-driven approch and component scan:

```
public interface ICart {}
```

--

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class Cart implements ICart {
    public static int dummy = 0;
    public Cart() {
        System.out.println("Cart::<init> with hashCode " + hashCode());
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Did I misunderstood the meaning of session bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's **a lot** of proxying and delegation going on.

This field

```
@Autowired 
private Cart cart;
```

where `Cart` is session scoped will be proxied as you can see in your logs

```
com.at.test.web.Cart$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2eb8334f
```

But this proxy is not wrapping a `Cart` object. It is wrapping a `SimpleBeanTargetSource` which takes care of getting a `Cart` bean from the `BeanFactory`.

Your bean definition attaches a `SessionScope` object which is responsible for checking your `HttpSession` through a `static` `ThreadLocal` field in `RequestContextHolder`. When  request is made to get a bean from the `BeanFactory`, it will delegate the action to the `SessionScope` object which will check the `HttpSession`, use the one there if it exists or create and register a new one if it doesn't.

You don't notice this with your test because

```
cart.hashCode()
```

delegates to the `SimpleBeanTargetSource` object (incorrectly, if you ask me). But if you did

```
cart.toString();
```

you would see the difference as that actually reaches the underlying `Cart` object.

---

Depending on the scope and proxying strategy you use, all this may be different, but the end goal is still achieved.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class HomeController {
  @Autowired 
  private Cart cart; <-- Proxy
```

The `Cart` instance that gets injected into the `HomeController` instance is only a proxy that delegates method calls to the "real" instance. The `Cart` class itself has no own method or state yet, so you won't notice any difference between sessions, of course.